# How to support all features of the group block in a classic theme?

Tags: wordpress

When using the WordPress block editor, the options available to me for a group block are different between themes.

When I add a group block using my own classic theme, I see an option to select a layout, then in the sidebar I get basic colour and typography options:

[image]

However, when I add a group block using the twenty twenty-three block theme, I again see the option to select a layout, but then I get a settings tab with layout and position options, plus a styles tab with options for colour, background, typography and dimensions:

[image]

I am especially interested in the option “inner blocks use content width”. Is there a way I can make this option visible when using my classic theme, perhaps via `add_theme_support()`?